# Android Fragment declaring in activity xml OR newInstance() factory method?

Tags: android, fragment

In my project I have an activity and multiple fragments.
 Currently the fragments are declared in my activity xml
 e.g:

```
    <fragment
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_do_you_know"
        android:name="myapp.fragments.DoYouKnowFragment"
        android:id="@+id/doYouKnowFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
    <fragment
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_whats_new"
        android:name="myapp.fragments.WhatsNewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/whatsNewFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

During activity initialization I get fragment references:

```
    mWhatsNewFragment = (WhatsNewFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.whatsNewFragment);
    mDoYouKnowFragment = (DoYouKnowFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.doYouKnowFragment);
```

On different actions I show one of the fragment and hide all other in FragmentManager transaction:

```
 protected void showFragment(BaseFragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
    BaseFragment visibleFragment = null;
    for (BaseFragment fr: mAllFragments) {
        if (fragment == fr) {
            transaction.show(fr);
            visibleFragment = fr;
        }
        else {
            transaction.hide(fr);
        }
    }
    transaction.commit();

    if (visibleFragment != null) {
        visibleFragment.onShow();
    }
}
```

I know that the other approach is to use newInstance() factory method for getting the fragment refereces.
 In that case I suppose I have to set the layout parameters (layout_width, layout_height) by code.
 But I think this is the right way if I want to pass initialization paramters to fragment.

So I wonder which approach is better.

And also is keeping references to all fragments is Ok or is better creating during transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. when you are creating newInstance factory method you do so because you want to pass some arguments from activity to fragment. normally you would do it with constructor but thats not an option when working with fragments. so thats only reason to create factory method for fragments other times you would just call default constructor. now in either case that doesnt mean that you will need to write layout paramets in code. there is nice workaround for that. you will create FrameLayout or any ViewGroup and set its layout parameters in xml. now at some point when you will want to add your fragment you can just add your fragment(or replace) in that ViewGroup. code is as simple as anything can get.

```
supportFragmentManager
.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.your_view_group_id, BadAssFragment.newInstance(someCoolData))
.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you, @ConfusedPup! I've edited the question to give more info of my situation.

Comment: okay there is no ultimately better approach. it depends on you and your personal preferences and what you are working on. I personally would rather to create FrameLayout and inflate fragment there and lots of my colleges also do that but I cant come and say that declaring your fragments in layout is wrong. because I think what is possible with first approach is also possible with second one.

Comment: and to answer your second question it doesnt really matter. if you need to have fragment reference to do something with it other than inflating you can do that and it wont cause any problems. but if you only use it only once I would suggest you to not create global variable for that.

Comment: In my application I have 6 fragments and the user can use the drawer menu to show one of them at any time. So I will not use them only once.